# How Do You change A ScrolledComposite's Horizontal Scroll Increment?

Tags: java, eclipse, scroll, swt

I have an application that displays a ScrolledComposite.  Users are complaining that the horizontal scrolling increment is too fine, i.e. each click on the horizontal scroll arrow currently moves the bar one pixel at a time.  They want individual clicks to cause greater horizontal movement.  Could someone explain how I could implement this?  A snippet of the code follows:

```
ScrolledComposite myScrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(parent, 
        SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);

if ( myScrolledComposite == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException("ScenePreView.java:  " + 
            "Method createPartControl()  " + 
            "ScrolledComposite myScrolledComposite == null."); 
}

Composite myComposite = new Composite(myScrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);

if ( myComposite == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException("ScenePreView.java:  " + 
            "Method createPartControl()  " + 
            "Composite myComposite == null."); 
}

myScrolledComposite.setContent(myComposite);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the sensetivity is not set in the OS?

Answer (score 3):

This should work pretty well and provide usable defaults. It should update automatically when the control inside the ScrolledComposite is resized.

```
myComposite.addControlListener( new ControlAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void controlResized( ControlEvent e ) {
        ScrollBar sbX = scrolledComposite.getHorizontalBar();
        if ( sbX != null ) {
            sbX.setPageIncrement( sbX.getThumb() );
            sbX.setIncrement( Math.max( 1, sbX.getThumb() / 5 ) );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the scrollbar from the composite and set it's increment.

myScrolledComposite.getVerticalBar().setIncrement(10);

Answer (score 0):

Use the setIncrement() method of the SWT Scrollbar class.  This lets you modify the amount by which the scroll region moves when the arrow buttons are pressed.
[See API Reference for SWT](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/ScrollBar.html)

Comment: Thank You.  I looked in the ScrolledComposite class, but didn't think to look in the Scrollbar class.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's more than you asked for, but I highly recommend checking out the [SWT animation toolkit](http://blog.richeton.com/swt-animation-toolkit/) which has an implementation of smooth scrolling. It will make your application way cooler.

You can check it out and see the sources - it's a good example (yet, a bit advanced) of how to play with the scrolling.